# how to avoid bundled products getting automatically assigned as upsell products for simple products

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I use Magento CE 1.8.1 once i create a bundle products by assigning some of my simple products    to the bundle items. Once created i can see that for all my simple products that has been used to create a bundle product includes the newly created bundled product as an upsell product.

How can i avoid this situation so that the bundled products should not be automatically assigned as upsell products unless i assign it manually.

I do not want to comment out or exclude the whole upsell.phtml file as i need it to assign for other simple products.I just want to exclude this functionality for simple products that are used to create bundle items.

Note:I want to sell my product seperately as well as bundle product i cannot use  visibility:not visible individually  nor status:disable options.

Comment: I noticed that with the "catalog_product_upsell" event dispatched by Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell, the upsell list gets filled by bundle products. That event is observed by Mage_Bundle_Model_Observer::appendUpsellProducts(). Don't know yet how to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/268228/#t475755

You need to edit this file `/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml`

And comment out/delete this part:

```
<catalog_product_upsell>
      <observers>
           <bundle_observer>
                 <class>bundle/observer</class>
                 <method>appendUpsellProducts</method>
           </bundle_observer>
      </observers>
</catalog_product_upsell>
```

Though, obviously you want to create a copy of this file and not overwrite the core file.

Hope that helps someone!